# Openmeetings 3.0.4 ubuntu 14.04 error while upload file PDF or document

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, upload, document, openmeetings

Please advise about the error below:

```
key: processXML
process: generateXMLDocument
command: null
exception: null
error: null
exitValue: 0
out: null
key: processThumb
process: generateBatchThumbByWidth
command: /usr/bin/convert -thumbnail 80 /opt/red5304/webapps/openmeetings/uploadtemp/files/ce29fe4f36bb1f956ac298729a5135b5.pdf /opt/red5304/webapps/openmeetings/upload/files/ce29fe4f36bb1f956ac298729a5135b5/_thumb_page-%04d.jpg 
exception: null
error: 
exitValue: 0
out: 
key: processSWF
process: generateSwf
command: /usr/local/bin/pdf2swf -s insertstop -s poly2bitmap -i -j 85 -s zoom=100 /opt/red5304/webapps/openmeetings/uploadtemp/files/ce29fe4f36bb1f956ac298729a5135b5.pdf /opt/red5304/webapps/openmeetings/upload/files/ce29fe4f36bb1f956ac298729a5135b5/ce29fe4f36bb1f956ac298729a5135b5.swf 
exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf": error=2, No such file or directory
error: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf": error=2, No such file or directory
exitValue: -1
out:
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://serverfault.com/questions/623604/install-pdf2swf-on-ubuntu-trusty-tahr14-04

Answer (score 0):

/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf

Have you installed pdf2swf ?

OpenMeetings has some system variables you can set in case it's not available in the standard $PATH variable.